# Dynamic Select Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a Select have "Primary Areas", and depending on the option you choose, another Select will update with the Secondary Areas it has.

here's an example of the table of Areas

[image]

Areas has many childrens, if an Area have "Parent_id = 0" is a main area.

[image]

This is the code of Select's:

```
<div class="grid_6">
  <% @main_area = Area.where(parent_id: 0) %>
  <%= f.label "Area Principal" %><br>
  <%= f.select :area_id, @main_area.collect{|u| [u.name, u.id]}, {:include_blank => "Seleccione Area principal"}, {:class => "style-select_medium"}  %>
  <!--<= f.collection_select :area_id, @main_area, :id, :name, prompt: "Seleciona Area principal", :class => "style-select_medium" %>-->


</div>
<div class="grid_6">
  <% @second_area = Area.where("parent_id <> 0") %>
  <%= f.label :"Area secundaria" %><br>
  <!--<= f.select :second_area_id, Area.select_minimal.map{|u| [u.name, u.id]}, {:include_blank => "Seleccione Area secundaria"}, {:class => "style-select_medium select_program"}  %>-->
  <%= f.collection_select :second_area_id, @second_area, :id, :name, prompt: "Seleciona Area secundaria", class: "style-select_medium select_program" %>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div><br>




  $( function() {
      $('#pp_data_basic_area_id').change(function (){
          let area_id = $('#pp_data_basic_area_id').val();
          if(area_id != ''){
              $.get("area_options", {cid: area_id}, function(data){
                  console.log(cid)
                  $(".select_program").html(data);
              } );
          }else{
              $(".select_program").html('');
          }
      });
  });
```

this will be shown in an index called pp_data_basics, pp_data_basics_Controller:

```
def area_options
    if Area.exists?(params[:cid])
      @second_area_options = Area.find(params[:cid]).children
    end

    #@second_area_options = Area.where(parent_id: params[:cid])
  end
```

here's the route:

```
  match 'pp_data_basics/area_options' => "pp_data_basics#area_options"
  resources :pp_data_basics
```

unfortunately it throws that error in the console:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Add the this line "render json: @second_area_options" in your area options method

Comment: ok, and what do I do after?

Comment: Can you post the results of rake routes?